# Cron job emails blank

Tags: plugins, themes, child-theme, email, cron

Was just wondering if anyone could throw some advice my way?

I have a site setup on SiteGround and have turned off the internal WordPress cron as this was hitting the server resources fairly hard.

I then set up a Cron Job using SiteGround's cPanel section. This is working fine however when the cron job runs I get an email but it is blank, well I say blank as it appeared that way to me but when the SiteGround tech support took a look at why this was happening he said that the body of the email actually contained this :

```
ï»¿
```

I'm not seeing that in my emails but perhaps it is hidden in some way?

Anyway he said that a plugin or even the fact that I'm using a child theme could be causing this.

Is that true as I thought that as the job is being run by the server instead of when someone visits the site that I should be getting some output?

Are there any plugins that might cause this sort of behaviour and what should I look for?

I'd really like to be able to get the emails and have something in them or I might as well not be receiving them as they don't contain anything of use to me.

Many thanks in advance to anyone for help with this one.

Best wishes,

Mark

Comment: It depends on how the cron is set up. You can set them up to email every time they fire, or only when an error happens. I would check error logs and also check cron setup to determine whether this is happening on every cron, or only on error/warnings. Once you know whether a problem is triggering this email, you can then start troubleshooting what may be causing the problem if that is the case.

Comment: This could also be a permission issue. Sometimes when you set up non WP crons, the Apache user triggering the cron is different from the WP user, so it doesn't have the right permissions to actually run the cron job. SiteGround ought to be able to verify whether the right "owner" is set for the cron job.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the ideas here. The email is set up so that I receive one every time the cron job runs and that is indeed working as I am receiving the emails, just that they're blank emails :-( The tech support said that it's probably a plugin or the theme which is causing this to happen though. Is that even possible? I would have thought that they wouldn't touch the process at all?

Comment: Personally I would set up a test site (defalt WP install with default theme and no extra plugins), then set up a cron job the same way you did for the production site. Possibly tweak so the cron fires more often so you can get results faster. That will tell you whether or not a theme or plugin is causing issues. If a default install gives you the same email results as your production site, then something else is in play. You may also want to try a different email address (different provider) since you are not able to see the email contents. Different provider may render the email differently.

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely a good idea. I will do that. Knowing if it's something on the server at play or something with my setup is definitely a great idea. Many thanks again.